# Passing QWidget* as function parameter doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I want to pass **QWidget** pointer to a function to get some widget back as a result of function actions. But the value of this pointer leaves the same as befoere.

Next code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>

class Test
{
public:
    QWidget *_widget;
    Test()
    {
        _widget = new QWidget;
    }
    void test_pointer(QWidget *w) const
    {
        w = _widget;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget *w = nullptr;
    Test t;
    t.test_pointer(w);
    qDebug() << w;

    return app.exec();
}
```

outputs

```
QWidget(0x0)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: @Botje Completely, yes. It works. I even didn't suspect about this feature.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the pointer as copy, which means the outside pointer is not modified by the inside assignment. Instead you have to pass a pointer or a reference to your QWidget*.

Comment: Thank you. @Botje has already directed me to related topic.